# Get Id of first div on drag

Tags: jquery, html, drag

Looking at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zima101/UxfNX/1/), I noticed that when dragging `car1` onto the first cell of the second row I am not able to put `car1` at first position `div`. When I run `alert` it always responds with the second cell id.

For example: I need to make the car rental to start from the first day of the month, however, rentals always start from the second day.

```
$('.ccarcellbook').draggable({
    helper : 'clone',
    cursor : 'move',
    snap : '.ccarcell',
    snapMode : 'inner'
});
$('.ccarcell').droppable({
   over: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
   },
   drop:function(event, ui) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give each car the same width, the full width of a cell. Ohterwise you are getting troubles like you have now.

When you want a wider car, you can give it an extra class. With the pseudo element you could make the car wider.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8x32n8uu/)**

```
.ccarcellbook.wider:after {
  width: 110px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: ok, your example is fine but it doesn't work with my code. I put idroom and date into id tag and when i move a booking details i can not get first id too,

![Valid XHTML](http://www.viagginelsalento.it/booking-calendar.jpg).

Comment: So if I understand you right, you are getting `undefined` with the alert?

Comment: no, i drag the booking period onto 03/07 and it goes onto 06/07, 3 days later. as the focus is on the third day not on the first one.

Comment: Are you sure that you have tried what I did in my demo. With only an image I can't help you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

my code is now that but there is something wrong.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">-->




    <style type="text/css">
    body {font-size:12px; }
    #principale {background-color:#eeeeee; }
    #contenitore { float:left; padding-right:3px; width:303px; border:2px solid #aaaaaa;}
    .camere {float:left; display:block; height:28px; border-top:1px solid #aaaaaa; border-left:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

    #calendario {width:70%; overflow-x:auto;}
    .testata_uno { width:320px;}
    .intestazione {float:left;}
    .width_h_60 {width:60%;}
    .width_h_33 {width:33%;}
    .width_h_20 {width:20%;}

    .width_h_160px {width:160px;}
    .width_h_70px {width:70px;}

    .height_40 {height:40px;}
    .height_30 {height:30px;}

    .bordo_destro {border-right:3px solid #aaaaaa;}


    .ccarrow { height:28px; /*padding-left:2px;*/ margin-bottom:2px;}

    .giorno_calendario { width:40px; height:15px; float:left; border-top:#aaaaaa 1px solid; border-bottom:#aaaaaa 1px solid; border-left:#aaaaaa 1px solid; text-align:center; }

    .ccarcell { width:40px; height:28px; float:left; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:#fbdda1 1px solid; border-left:#fbdda1 1px solid; background-color:#fff; }

    .ccarcellbook { width:40px; height:28px; float:left; color:#FFFFFF; cursor:hand; background-color:#36c20b; border-bottom:#fbdda1 1px solid; border-left:#fbdda1 1px solid; border-radius:6px; }

    .ccarcellbook.wider:after {
      width: 28px;
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      background-color: green;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .wide {clear:both;}
    </style>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="principale">
        <div id="contenitore">
            <div class="testata_uno height_30">
                <form action="" method="get">
                    <select name='mese'>
                        <option value='01'>Gennaio</option>
                        <option value='02'>Febbraio</option>
                        <option value='03'>Marzo</option>
                        <option value='04'>Aprile</option>
                        <option value='05'>Maggio</option>
                        <option value='06'>Giugno</option>
                        <option value='07' selected='selected'>Luglio</option>
                        <option value='08'>Agosto</option>
                        <option value='09'>Settembre</option>
                        <option value='10'>Ottobre</option>
                        <option value='11'>Novembre</option>
                        <option value='12'>Dicembre</option>
                                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="visualizza" value="Vai" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="testata_uno">
                <div class="intestazione width_h_160px bordo_destro"><b>Risorsa</b></div>
                <div class="intestazione width_h_70px bordo_destro"><b>Capienza</b></div>
                <div class="intestazione width_h_70px"><b>Stato</b></div>
            </div>
            <div class="wide"></div>
            <div class="testata_uno">
                <div class="camere width_h_160px">[#1] Car 1 </div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px">4 sits</div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px; border-left:4px solid #1a9d13;">Pronta</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wide"></div>
            <div class="testata_uno">
                <div class="camere width_h_160px">[#2]Car 2</div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px">6 sits</div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px; border-left:4px solid #1a9d13;">Pronta</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wide"></div>
            <div class="testata_uno">
                <div class="camere width_h_160px">[#3]CAR 3</div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px">6 sits</div>
                <div class="camere width_h_70px" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px; border-left:4px solid #1a9d13;">Pronta</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wide"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="calendario">

                    <div class="height_30" align="center">Luglio 2016</div>

                <div style="float:left; width:1280px;">

    <div class="giorno_calendario">01</div><div class="giorno_calendario">02</div><div class="giorno_calendario">03</div><div class="giorno_calendario">04</div><div class="giorno_calendario">05</div><div class="giorno_calendario">06</div><div class="giorno_calendario">07</div><div class="giorno_calendario">08</div><div class="giorno_calendario">09</div><div class="giorno_calendario">10</div><div class="giorno_calendario">11</div><div class="giorno_calendario">12</div><div class="giorno_calendario">13</div><div class="giorno_calendario">14</div><div class="giorno_calendario">15</div><div class="giorno_calendario">16</div><div class="giorno_calendario">17</div><div class="giorno_calendario">18</div><div class="giorno_calendario">19</div><div class="giorno_calendario">20</div><div class="giorno_calendario">21</div><div class="giorno_calendario">22</div><div class="giorno_calendario">23</div><div class="giorno_calendario">24</div><div class="giorno_calendario">25</div><div class="giorno_calendario">26</div><div class="giorno_calendario">27</div><div class="giorno_calendario">28</div><div class="giorno_calendario">29</div><div class="giorno_calendario">30</div><div class="giorno_calendario">31</div>           </div>

        <div class="ccarrow">
            <!--<div style="float:left; position:fixed; padding-right:3px; width:240px; border-right:2px solid orange;">[#1]TRILO TP VM P101 </div>-->

            <div style="float:left; width:1280px;">

    <div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-01"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-02"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-03"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-04"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-05"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-06"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-07"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-08"></div><div class="ccarcellbook wider" style="width: 573px" id="1_90_2016-07-09">Booking People 1</div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-23"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-24"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-25"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-26"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-27"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-28"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-29"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-30"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="1_0_2016-07-31"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ccarrow">
            <!--<div style="float:left; position:fixed; padding-right:3px; width:240px; border-right:2px solid orange;">[#2]TRILO TP VM P102</div>-->

            <div style="float:left; width:1280px;">

    <div class="ccarcell" id="2_0_2016-07-01"></div><div class="ccarcellbook wider" style="width: 573px" id="2_91_2016-07-02">Booking People 2</div><div class="ccarcellbook wider" style="width: 573px" id="2_89_2016-07-16">Booking People 3</div><div class="ccarcell" id="2_0_2016-07-30"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="2_0_2016-07-31"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ccarrow">
            <!--<div style="float:left; position:fixed; padding-right:3px; width:240px; border-right:2px solid orange;">[#3]TRILO TP VM P103</div>-->

            <div style="float:left; width:1280px;">

    <div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-01"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-02"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-03"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-04"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-05"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-06"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-07"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-08"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-09"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-10"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-11"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-12"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-13"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-14"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-15"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-16"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-17"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-18"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-19"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-20"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-21"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-22"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-23"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-24"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-25"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-26"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-27"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-28"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-29"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-30"></div><div class="ccarcell" id="3_0_2016-07-31"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end calendario -->
        </div>

    <div id="risposta"></div>

    </body>

    </html>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){

    $('.ccarcellbook').draggable({
            helper : 'clone',
            cursor : 'move',
            snap : '.ccarcell',
            snapMode : 'inner'
    });
    $('.ccarcell').droppable({
           over: function(event, ui) {
                var $this = $(this);
           },
           drop:function(event, ui) {
                alert($(this).attr('id'))
           }
    });
    });//]]> 

    </script>
```